# How do I rewrite this to be more LINQy?

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I have this set of data here. Events has a property `EventGroups` that is of type `List<Groups>`

```
List<Events> e;
List<Groups> g;

// Get the data from the database using dapper
using( var con = DataAccessMaster.GetOpenConnection( ) ) {
    using( var multi = con.QueryMultiple( sprocname, new { StartDate = fromDate, EndDate = toDate }, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure ) ) {
        e = multi.Read<Events>( ).ToList( );
        g = multi.Read<Groups>().ToList();
    }
}

// Only put the groups that belong to one another within the related event so that when we goto bind it will be painless
foreach ( var ev in e ) {
    ev.EventGroups = new List<Groups>();
    foreach ( Groups group in g.Where( Groups => ( ev.EventID == Groups.EventID ) ) ) {
        ev.EventGroups.Add( group );
    }
}

return e;
```

I feel like the last block could be rewritten more cleanly than it is. What can I do to make this cleaner?

Comment: Not to be flippant, but if you install ReSharper it'll suggest an elegant LINQ solution once it sees that 'foreach...', if there is one.

Comment: @rafe but it didn't, so that's what I don't know how to make it better :S

Comment: CodeRush will too for the more trivial cases.

Comment: Celebrate! You're better than you thought. Maybe it's fine. Make 'Groups group' 'var groups' or something else - it's confusing as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.ToList Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to turn an IEnumerable<T> into a new List<T>:

```
foreach (var ev in e)
{
    ev.EventGroups = g.Where(groups => ev.EventID == groups.EventID)
                      .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse the inner loop with `ToList()`.

```
foreach ( var ev in e ) {
    ev.EventGroups = g.Where( Groups => ( ev.EventID == Groups.EventID ) ).ToList();
}
```

The outer loop is already as LINQy as it can get, because it is a side-effecting loop and those are not LINQy.

Comment: Who downvoted this? ~ @Martinho speaking of side effects ... is this sane code?

Comment: I wonder the same. The code is fine. The side effects I'm talking about here is the assignment.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's what I was asking in the last Q

Answer (score 1):

This for instance

```
ev.EventGroups = g.Where( Groups => ( ev.EventID == Groups.EventID )).ToList();
```

comes to mind.

Comment: Looks fine to me - what is the problem @Marthinho? (besides the outer loop missing from the code example)

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I was commenting on an older version that wasn't as correct. And now I can't undo my downvote because the edit was made within the window of 5 minutes where edits are not edits :(