# How can I find the <script> element where my JavaScript is declared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a fragment of HTML/JavaScript that gets loaded into a host web page dynamically, I need the JavaScript fragment to know about where it is declared. Is there a way of finding the  tag that the currently executing JavaScript was loaded from?

The HTML fragment is loaded from the same host as the current page using a jQuery ajax call and inserting the result into the DOM.

**Edit:**

What I really am trying to do, and the above would be one potential way of implementing it, is to have a fragment of HTML/JavaScript being loaded dynamically and a known initialization function be called by the host page with some parameters. Any portable solution that would allow for the worlds to meet would solve my problem.

Comment: jQuery is just an extension over javascript, it's not magic. Additionally, how are you initially declaring the <script> block? will it have any sort of id attribute? And what on earth are you going to use where it's declared to have anything to do with the execution of the javascript?

Comment: @jcolebrand, yes, jQuery is just a library and if it's possible to do it in jQuery it's automatically possible to do it in JavaScript, but there may potentially be a safer/nicer way of doing it in jQuery than plain JavaScript. It will not have an id attribute as the same fragment may be loaded into the DOM more than once.

Comment: @jcolebrand, Sparky672, edited question to include the bigger problem.

Comment: What does that even mean? (cc @Sparky672 since he doesn't know how to at folks) ... I think that the way you're telling us you're approaching this is totally wrong. I think you need to start completely over with a well described story. I don't care if this is the next big idea that will make trillions and destroy the stock market with the IPO, if you want plain answers, ask plain questions and give plain details. I think you're doing it wrong. I want to help you do it right.

Comment: I would flip it around if I were you.  Have the "parameters" the script needs simply stored somewhere accessible on the page, like in "data-foo" attributes on the `<body>` tag or something, and then have the script simply find them on its own.  It's much better design practice to keep script code out of pages entirely.

Comment: @Pointy, this would work for the basic case, but the parameters are specific to the module and would have to be removed after the module has been loaded. Also, the module will somehow need to know where it is in order to dynamically update its UI, either by finding it itself or being told from the outside.

Comment: That's just not a very good way of going about things.  Your pages shouldn't be loading lots of different scripts anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but saying "I just can't! I'll be giving away all our core business secrets discussing how I load a script and need to do a thing based on how it got loaded!!!" is not valid. All questions can be reduced to not showing off business secrets but still demonstrating with code. This is not a valid question. VtC.

Comment: I agree with @jcolebrand... this question needs a lot of work before anyone is going to be able to answer.  Anything else will result in pure speculation.

Comment: @jcolebrand, you're entitles to your opinion, but the question is hardly vague. What may be vague is the reason why I need this, which is, however, a separate concern.

Comment: No, what is vague is _how_ you're doing it in the first place. I could propose a lot of answers, but every one would be a crapshoot on what you're doing initially. Would you like me to link you to a good question? Look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434601/how-do-i-rewrite-this-to-be-more-linqy where I put "gasp" my business logic that is internal need only ... but what's more "gasp" is that I didn't reveal anything! But I used code and asked for help.

Comment: @jcolebrand, some more detail added on how the fragment gets loaded ...

Comment: No you didn't. That was evident from what you already said. Give us the narrative on what it is you're trying to do. Tell us a story. Make it friendly and nice. Give us a workflow. What the hell do you want the end result to be. I have already enumerated with my friends three different ways to solve your problem, which aren't even gauranteed to be accurate. I'll share them with you:

Comment: ~ I can think of three different ways to solve it
~ have a handler return javascript but accept get parameters
~ use a jsonp style callback with templating
~ have some body tags that deal with the issue at hand and have the script be intelligent

Comment: @jcolebrand, for this scenario, I cannot dynamically generate content on the server side. The only viable solution may be to set globals alive while the HTML fragment is inserted into the DOM (and its script tags evaluated), but it's a workaround - not a solution to my original question. I do however realize that you've given up answering this.

Comment: @Freed on the contrary. I only look for an actual example of what your problem is. I've offered three potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use id attribute for your script tag and find it by `#mylib` selector or find it using tag&attr selector `script[src="mylib.js"]`.

Comment: This is where I was going but after reading the comments, this won't work as-is. It needs something more.

Comment: The same HTML fragment may be loaded into the DOM multiple times, so neither one of the approaches would work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Freed ~ You know what? I wrote a dashboard (think iGoogle) for work that injects the exact same HTML fragment (excepting that the data contained therein is different, but the templates are bog-standard the same every single time) and I don't have the problem's you're anticipating. Do what I asked, and give us a full narrative story with code. Else I'll get the question closed.

Comment: @jcolebrand, this is as much context as I am able to provide. You may not think doing this is a good idea, but I don't see how that makes it less of a valid question.

Comment: @Freed It's an invalid question because it's too vague to be answered. You have _not_ provided enough information to adequately answer the question, as I indicated on the answer here.